# Transferring OV7670 data with SPI port

Tags: spi

I bought an OV7670 camera and I would like to use the following code:
https://github.com/ComputerNerd/ov7670-no-ram-arduino-uno

But I wonder whether it is possible to use SPI instead of I2C when I transfer the image data through Arduino to other breakout boards.

Answer (score 1):

I2C is not used to get the pixel data. That is used only to configure the ov7670. You can read the pixel data by reading the IO PORTS and then send the data via SPI.